# Pi OMV NAS server: Access over internet

Tags: networking, samba, file-server

I am using OpenMediaVault for NAS management installed on Raspberry Pi. I am able to access my shared drive on my network using File Manager. I would like to access it from the internet (Different network). I have static IP connection and have done the port forwarding. I am able to access the OpenMediaVault configuration page from other network, but cannot access the shared drive.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I am using SMB to access shared files.

Comment: How do you access the files normally? SMB? You set-up "the" port forwarding. Also for SMB (if you use that)? Does your ISP filter dangerous protocols (like SMB by the way)? Pleas add the information to your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes I am using SMB. I am not sure whether my ISP blocks SMB protocol.

Comment: And do you have a port forwarding rule for port 445? Do you try to connect to the public IP? Note that exposing SMB to the Internet is generally a bad idea, but I do not know your use-case.

Comment: Yes I have done port forwarding for 445. I have found the issue, please see if you can help
I have hosted a server on Network A (ISP1). When I connect to the server from Network B (ISP2) I am not able to access it. When I tried it with my neighbour's network (ISP3) I am able to access it. My ISP might be blocking SMB protocols. 
Are you aware about any other protocols (FTP, SFTP, SSH etc.) through which I can do this. I want to create a storage server with user management (just like OpenMediaVault) and want to access it from anywhere. Also I want use Map Network drive feature on windows.

Comment: I would look at WebDAV. https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/31905-raspberry-pi-webdav-omv5/ may give some hints, but I use neither OMV nor webdav at the moment.